# How can I create an azure application or client ID to fetch resources with rest?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, firefox-addon-webextensions, azure-cli

I'm building a browser extension. I want on install to open a popup where user is asked: hey, do you want to allow 'NewBrowserExtension' to access resources in Azure? After user logs in and clicks yes I want to be able to use APIs to fetch the resource URLs like this one https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/Resources/List I want to authenticate using this API https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/identity/launchWebAuthFlow and I need the user_impersonation scope. Here is an example with an extension doing the same with google https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/tree/master/google-userinfo

Current status:
I ran

```
az ad app create --display-name NewBrowserExtension
```

I used the appId in my browser extension and it starts the sign in flow which is awesome.

The first problem is that I need to set a redirect URL in the app some place to tell it to redirect back to the extension. I don't know where I can set this or what az cli commands to run.

The second problem is that I have a work subscription and a personal subscription. My extension can only start the log in flow in my personal account since there is where I made the app. I want my app to work on everybody's subscription.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Hi did you have a chance to look into my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`az ad app update`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/app?view=azure-cli-latest#az_ad_app_update) to set the reply url.

For example:

```
az ad app update --id 93dde3da-9fca-47dd-aee2-409b402ffed3 --add replyUrls "https://example.com/test"
```

Use `az account set --subscription <name or id>` to switch your active subscription.